# How to save spring integration message header into database

Tags: spring, header, integration, message

What would be the easiest and best solution for saving spring header information into database?
I know outbound component that's not the question.

The question is how I can do it without specify-ing header elements in the sql one by one?

Are there any builtin solution for that problem which could adopt the changes when new header elements are added to the message header?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, there is no such a solution, because with RDBMS we have `schema` bottleneck.
Even if we could do something like this:

```
insert into headers value (:headers)
```

We have to specify any new column in the target DB table.

That's why any NOSQL DB is better for that case. E.g. MongoDb can simply accepts whole `Message` and stores it to the `Document` with all headers.

Even if we can Spring Integration scenario make with JPA adapters just to use `<jpa:outbound-channel-adapter>`, where the message `payload` is an `entity` for our header, we need to add a new property to the `entity` to allow JPA to get deal with them.

However, I think that the `new columns in DB` isn't en issue for your, and from other side `MessageHeader` is a `Map`, so you can iterate over its entries and build `INSERT INTO...`  statement at runtime for each message.

Hope I haven't missed something...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I hoped that there are some other solutions. Now I know the onyl working solution is to interate through header elements and save them to db. 
The disadvantage of this solution is that you have to write your own java code to do it and there is no - built in - solution for that problem.

Comment: M-m-m. Do you know similar solution for something else, not our `Map` with headers?